# How to remove a file attached in a USPTO EFS WEB application?

Tags: filing, uspto

I added a file which was found to contain some PDF errors (missing font) and the EFS web site is asking me to remove the file and reattach a correct version.

Alas, I can't find any "remove" button or link anywhere, even when going back to the "attach documents" stage.

How do I remove the file without restarting a new application from scratch?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

click the Revalidate button to get a screen which includes Delete buttons.